# Optaplanner 7.9.0 Can't unmarshall input string ERROR calling REST API

Tags: rest, drools, optaplanner, kie

Hi I'm a novice about optaplanner so after installing the last versioni of kie-wb and kie-server (7.9) on wildfly 11, I'm tryng samples projects to understand how to use the Optaplanner features.
I installed two built-in samples: optaCloud and Employee_rostering samples. With first one all was ok, installation, configuration and deploy to kie-server and REST api call with SOAPUI as rest client goes well (also submit the `xml|json` sample data for a solution).

For the second one, the installation and deploy was ok too, but the main problem was that in the official documentation no samples data (`xml|json`) was present, to submit to the solver via post to request a solution.

After a google search, finally, I found this article on red-hat site ([Employee Rostering sample](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_decision_manager/7.0/html/creating_and_solving_the_employee_roster_problem_for_red_hat_business_optimizer_using_decision_central/wb-employee-rostering-solver-configuration-proc#wb-employee-rostering-register-solver-proc)) ... reading the content I can see it's the same sample (data-model, data-object and drl rules) present in kie-wb sample project   "Employee_rostering" I used above.
So I tried to use the `xml` data sample in this article to submit a solution request to the solver. The problem seems to be with this xml sample data, infact when I submit the rest request with SOAPUI with this xml as body the response of kie-server is `500 Internal Server Error` with body:

```
<data contentType="text/plain;charset=UTF-8" contentLength="2950">
  <![CDATA["Unexpected error during processing: Can't unmarshall input string: 
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.EmployeeRoster>
        <employeeList>
          <employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee>
            <name>John</name>
              <skills>
        ....
```

has anyone experience about this? Any suggestion/info is very appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] REST request must contain following headers

```
authorization: Basic cGxhbm5lcjpQbGFubmVyMTIzXw==
X-KIE-ContentType: xstream
content-type: application/xml
```

in SOAP-UI I added a custom header `X-KIE-ContentType: xstream` (auth basic and content type was already ok).
This is the sample XML body content that I submit to the solver successfully

```
        <employeerostering.employeerostering.EmployeeRoster>
          <employeeList>
            <employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee>
              <name>John</name>
              <skills>
                <employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill>
                  <name>reading</name>
                </employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill>
              </skills>
            </employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee>
            <employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee>
              <name>Mary</name>
              <skills>
                <employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill>
                  <name>writing</name>
                </employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill>
              </skills>
            </employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee>
            <employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee>
              <name>Petr</name>
              <skills>
                <employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill>
                  <name>speaking</name>
                </employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill>
              </skills>
            </employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee>
          </employeeList>
          <shiftList>
            <employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift>
              <timeslot>
                <startTime>2017-01-01T00:00:00</startTime>
                <endTime>2017-01-01T01:00:00</endTime>
              </timeslot>
              <requiredSkill reference="../../../employeeList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee/skills/employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill"/>
            </employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift>
            <employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift>
              <timeslot reference="../../employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift/timeslot"/>
              <requiredSkill reference="../../../employeeList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee[3]/skills/employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill"/>
            </employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift>
            <employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift>
              <timeslot reference="../../employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift/timeslot"/>
              <requiredSkill reference="../../../employeeList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee[2]/skills/employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill"/>
            </employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift>
          </shiftList>
          <skillList>
            <employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill reference="../../employeeList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee/skills/employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill"/>
            <employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill reference="../../employeeList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee[3]/skills/employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill"/>
            <employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill reference="../../employeeList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee[2]/skills/employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill"/>
          </skillList>
          <timeslotList>
            <employeerostering.employeerostering.Timeslot reference="../../shiftList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift/timeslot"/>
          </timeslotList>
          <dayOffRequestList/>
          <shiftAssignmentList>
            <employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
                <shift reference="../../../shiftList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift" />
            </employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
            <employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
                <shift reference="../../../shiftList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift[2]" />
            </employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
          </shiftAssignmentList>
        </employeerostering.employeerostering.EmployeeRoster>
```

The solution response (as JSON):

```
        {
            "container-id": "employeerostering_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT",
            "solver-id": "solver-1",
            "solver-config-file": "employeerostering/employeerostering/EmployeeRosteringSolverConfig.solver.xml",
            "status": "SOLVING",
            "score": {
                "value": "0hard/-2soft",
                "scoreClass": "org.optaplanner.core.api.score.buildin.hardsoft.HardSoftScore"
            },
            "best-solution": {
                "employeerostering.employeerostering.EmployeeRoster": {
                    "employeeList": [
                        {
                            "name": "John",
                            "skills": [
                                {
                                    "name": "reading"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Mary",
                            "skills": [
                                {
                                    "name": "writing"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Petr",
                            "skills": [
                                {
                                    "name": "speaking"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "shiftList": [
                        {
                            "timeslot": {
                                "startTime": {
                                    "dayOfYear": 1,
                                    "dayOfWeek": "SUNDAY",
                                    "dayOfMonth": 1,
                                    "monthValue": 1,
                                    "year": 2017,
                                    "month": "JANUARY",
                                    "hour": 0,
                                    "minute": 0,
                                    "second": 0,
                                    "nano": 0,
                                    "chronology": {
                                        "calendarType": "iso8601",
                                        "id": "ISO"
                                    }
                                },
                                "endTime": {
                                    "dayOfYear": 1,
                                    "dayOfWeek": "SUNDAY",
                                    "dayOfMonth": 1,
                                    "monthValue": 1,
                                    "year": 2017,
                                    "month": "JANUARY",
                                    "hour": 1,
                                    "minute": 0,
                                    "second": 0,
                                    "nano": 0,
                                    "chronology": {
                                        "calendarType": "iso8601",
                                        "id": "ISO"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "requiredSkill": {
                                "name": "reading"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "timeslot": {
                                "startTime": {
                                    "dayOfYear": 1,
                                    "dayOfWeek": "SUNDAY",
                                    "dayOfMonth": 1,
                                    "monthValue": 1,
                                    "year": 2017,
                                    "month": "JANUARY",
                                    "hour": 0,
                                    "minute": 0,
                                    "second": 0,
                                    "nano": 0,
                                    "chronology": {
                                        "calendarType": "iso8601",
                                        "id": "ISO"
                                    }
                                },
                                "endTime": {
                                    "dayOfYear": 1,
                                    "dayOfWeek": "SUNDAY",
                                    "dayOfMonth": 1,
                                    "monthValue": 1,
                                    "year": 2017,
                                    "month": "JANUARY",
                                    "hour": 1,
                                    "minute": 0,
                                    "second": 0,
                                    "nano": 0,
                                    "chronology": {
                                        "calendarType": "iso8601",
                                        "id": "ISO"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "requiredSkill": {
                                "name": "speaking"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "timeslot": {
                                "startTime": {
                                    "dayOfYear": 1,
                                    "dayOfWeek": "SUNDAY",
                                    "dayOfMonth": 1,
                                    "monthValue": 1,
                                    "year": 2017,
                                    "month": "JANUARY",
                                    "hour": 0,
                                    "minute": 0,
                                    "second": 0,
                                    "nano": 0,
                                    "chronology": {
                                        "calendarType": "iso8601",
                                        "id": "ISO"
                                    }
                                },
                                "endTime": {
                                    "dayOfYear": 1,
                                    "dayOfWeek": "SUNDAY",
                                    "dayOfMonth": 1,
                                    "monthValue": 1,
                                    "year": 2017,
                                    "month": "JANUARY",
                                    "hour": 1,
                                    "minute": 0,
                                    "second": 0,
                                    "nano": 0,
                                    "chronology": {
                                        "calendarType": "iso8601",
                                        "id": "ISO"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "requiredSkill": {
                                "name": "writing"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "skillList": [
                        {
                            "name": "reading"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "speaking"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "writing"
                        }
                    ],
                    "timeslotList": [
                        {
                            "startTime": {
                                "dayOfYear": 1,
                                "dayOfWeek": "SUNDAY",
                                "dayOfMonth": 1,
                                "monthValue": 1,
                                "year": 2017,
                                "month": "JANUARY",
                                "hour": 0,
                                "minute": 0,
                                "second": 0,
                                "nano": 0,
                                "chronology": {
                                    "calendarType": "iso8601",
                                    "id": "ISO"
                                }
                            },
                            "endTime": {
                                "dayOfYear": 1,
                                "dayOfWeek": "SUNDAY",
                                "dayOfMonth": 1,
                                "monthValue": 1,
                                "year": 2017,
                                "month": "JANUARY",
                                "hour": 1,
                                "minute": 0,
                                "second": 0,
                                "nano": 0,
                                "chronology": {
                                    "calendarType": "iso8601",
                                    "id": "ISO"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "dayOffRequestList": [],
                    "shiftAssignmentList": [
                        {
                            "shift": {
                                "timeslot": {
                                    "startTime": {
                                        "dayOfYear": 1,
                                        "dayOfWeek": "SUNDAY",
                                        "dayOfMonth": 1,
                                        "monthValue": 1,
                                        "year": 2017,
                                        "month": "JANUARY",
                                        "hour": 0,
                                        "minute": 0,
                                        "second": 0,
                                        "nano": 0,
                                        "chronology": {
                                            "calendarType": "iso8601",
                                            "id": "ISO"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "endTime": {
                                        "dayOfYear": 1,
                                        "dayOfWeek": "SUNDAY",
                                        "dayOfMonth": 1,
                                        "monthValue": 1,
                                        "year": 2017,
                                        "month": "JANUARY",
                                        "hour": 1,
                                        "minute": 0,
                                        "second": 0,
                                        "nano": 0,
                                        "chronology": {
                                            "calendarType": "iso8601",
                                            "id": "ISO"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "requiredSkill": {
                                    "name": "reading"
                                }
                            },
                            "employee": {
                                "name": "John",
                                "skills": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "reading"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "shift": {
                                "timeslot": {
                                    "startTime": {
                                        "dayOfYear": 1,
                                        "dayOfWeek": "SUNDAY",
                                        "dayOfMonth": 1,
                                        "monthValue": 1,
                                        "year": 2017,
                                        "month": "JANUARY",
                                        "hour": 0,
                                        "minute": 0,
                                        "second": 0,
                                        "nano": 0,
                                        "chronology": {
                                            "calendarType": "iso8601",
                                            "id": "ISO"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "endTime": {
                                        "dayOfYear": 1,
                                        "dayOfWeek": "SUNDAY",
                                        "dayOfMonth": 1,
                                        "monthValue": 1,
                                        "year": 2017,
                                        "month": "JANUARY",
                                        "hour": 1,
                                        "minute": 0,
                                        "second": 0,
                                        "nano": 0,
                                        "chronology": {
                                            "calendarType": "iso8601",
                                            "id": "ISO"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "requiredSkill": {
                                    "name": "speaking"
                                }
                            },
                            "employee": {
                                "name": "Petr",
                                "skills": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "speaking"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "score": "0hard/-2soft"
                }
            }
        }
```